# Django - more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I'm getting this error for some reason on the server:

**more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

on this line:

**asoc = Association.objects.get(id=asoc_pk)** (commented down below in the code)

but when I run it in localhost it works just fine.

Been looking for similar solutions here with no help.

Hopefully you can see other solutions that I can't figure out.

Still new to this and appreciate your help, folks!

---

models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
   ...
   association= models.ForeignKey(Association)


   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Administrator'



class Association(models.Model):
   asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ...


   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Association'
```

---

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                          {'form': form})

        else:
            ...
            asoc_pk = Association.objects.filter(asoc_name=request.user.association)
            asoc = Association.objects.get(id=asoc_pk)    **#ERROR here but why?**
            ...
            Administrator.objects.create_user(...
                                              association=asoc,    
                                              ...)
            user = authenticate(...
                                association=asoc,
                                ...)
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'admin/signup.html',
                      {'form': SignUpForm()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        asoc_pk = Association.objects.filter(asoc_name=request.user.association)
        asoc = Association.objects.get(id=asoc_pk)    **#ERROR here but why?**
```

Because your Association model does not enforce a unique constraint on the `asoc_name` property. So that makes it very likely that there can be more than one record that matches `request.user.association`. The solution is to make that column unique. you will have to clear out the duplicates first though (and there are plenty of answers here on how to clear duplicates)

Comment: Then remember to change `filter` to `get`, like this: `"asoc_pk = Association.objects.get(asoc_name=request.user.association)"`

Comment: @e4c5 - THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!! Been struggling for days with this problem. Always something new to learn, and sorry for the delay.

Comment: @danihp - no need, it works just fine without changing it. Appreciate the suggestion =D

Comment: Hi, I will delete comments in short to keep clean the site. Thanks.

Comment: glad to have helped. All the best with your project